# Is it possible to get crispy, crunchy carrots from canned carrots?

Tags: carrots

I understand this is basically just a question of laziness and as such if the answer is 'no' that's perfectly fine, but as someone that enjoys the convenience of canned carrots and also enjoys a crisp, crunchy carrot slice...

Is there any way to prepare canned carrots such that they would be crispy and crunchy like stir-fried fresh carrots can be?

Comment: Ref to cross-link in the sidebar, but I don't think they quite qualify as dupes - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/100543/is-there-a-way-to-harden-soft-braised-carrots

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, once its [over] cooked that's it, there's no going back.

If you dry them you will eventually get… you guessed it - dried, cooked carrots. Think 'packet soup' minestrone, or the unfortunately named 'spring vegetable' with salty knotty chunks of partially reconstituted ingredient - a childhood delight.

Once the cell walls are gone, there's no rebuilding them; nor will you ever get them to taste like fresh food again.

Canning is a 'heat-blast' technique to ensure only that the contents are absolutely sterile. It is not a technique which at all concerns itself with the texture or flavour of that result.

If you like canned carrots - & someone must, they seem to sell enough - then be happy with canned carrots.

If you like fresh, then you have no choice but to get them fresh.

If it's pure laziness (you said it, not me ;) then supermarkets sell them ready-prepped… baton/julienne, round cut or grated. They cost more [but so do canned] & they taste unsurprisingly ***almost*** *exactly like ones you prepared yourself*.

Comment: Obviously quite a bit late, but thank you for mentioning the ready-prepped fresh carrots at the supermarket. I've been doing that since and everything is better. :)